# Cross platform projects and data classes from nugets

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, cross-platform

We are building nugets for Android and iOS which, both of them, produce a result as a class holding data only.

```
public struct ResultData
{
    public double dScore;
    public string strPhrase;
    public Info[] details;
}
```

Both the Android and the iOS nuget produce this data.

My question is how to declare this data structure/class within the platform neutral code so that I can correctly capture it from the calling method, in a platform independant manner ?

Is this possible ?

---

**Edit : extra info**

As stated in the title, I am in the context of a cross platform project, ie mobile project.  So we have three layers - a platform neutral layer, an Android layer and an iOS layer.

Each of the platform specific layers (Android and iOS) import a platform specific native library nuget.

Both of these library nugets will produce the `ResultData` object to be consumed by the platform neutral layer.

Hopefully this will help.

---

Edit #2

Tried the suggested solution of creating a seperate library to hold the definition of this data structure.

However, the compilation fails systematically with errors such as

`Class.cs(118,16,118,32): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

So I cannot go down that road !

Comment: [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is platform independent.

Comment: Nugets that are built for Android and iOS are platform specific - hence my question !

Comment: If this is just a class library containing nothing specific to any platform, then make it target .NET standard, then you don't have you make separate ones for each platform. You mentioned _"the platform neutral code"_ ...so do you have some platform-neutral library / project already? It's not entirely clear what you mean.

Comment: Description updated

Comment: _"Both of these library nugets will produce the ResultData object to be consumed by the platform neutral layer."_  ...ok so why can't you simply move the ResultData class definition into the neutral layer? Is something specific preventing this? Is it because the Android/iOS layers don't reference this layer and also need to refer to ResultData? In that case perhaps you need an "entities" library which is platform neutral, and is referenced by all your other components, to enable you to share common objects across all of them.

Comment: "why can't you simply move the ResultData class definition into the neutral layer" :- because it is produced by the imported nugets and not from the projects Android/iOS layers.

Comment: Ok so why can't you take it out of those nugets and into a shared "entities" library? I don't understand.

Comment: ok, so what is a "shared entities library" and where is it found in the list of solution types, please ?

Comment: In C# terms it's a class library like any other. "shared entities library" is just my name describing what it represents in your application, logically (i.e. a set of classes representing data structures, which need to be re-used across several different components of your application architecture). I expect you'd want to make it target .NET Standard or maybe .NET 5 (not sure what framework the rest of your application is targeting?)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try ...

Comment: "I cannot go down that road !"...how about just fixing the error?

Comment: I have spent far too much time trying to find how to fix this error and have concluded that, for an iOS nuget, it is not possible

Comment: So the iOS nuget library is throwing that? Just because you removed one class? Or did you change other stuff? (I was assuming your new class library was throwing it, but not sure how you ended up in this scenario with an existing lib)

Comment: I created a new .net standard library containing only the data definition.  I then added this library as a reference into the iOS nuget project, removing the previous definition.  The error was thrown when compiling the nuget project.

Comment: What .NET version does the iOS lib target? What version of .NET Standard did you target the new lib at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224653/discussion-between-simon-and-adyson).

Comment: @Simon So you solve your problem now?

Comment: Hi @CherryBu-MSFT, no, this would seem impossible within VS 2019

Comment: @Simon Can you try to add the missing reference(s) manually by opening the projects .csproj file in a text editor? I search one thread that you can take a look:[add a reference to assembly](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1768/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly)

Comment: Tried this already and it does not work, it still gives multiple declarations errors.

Comment: @Simon Any update? Have solved your problem now?

Answer (score 0):

The result of all my investigations - it is definitely not possible to do this with the actual version of xamarin and VS2019.

I have had to subsequently abandon this approach and use a different strategy to pass the information over the different layers - a JSON string, which can then be transformed into the required data structures/classes at the top layer.

Thanks to all who attempted to help here.